# Как узнать размер массива указателей с помощью sizeof()?

Tags: c++, массивы, указатели, sizeof

У меня есть функция, в которую я передаю массив указателей. В функции я хочу узнать с помощью sizeof() сколько места занимает массив указателей str. Я понимаю, что если я вывожу sizeof(str), то получаю размер одного указателя (в моем случае 8 байт). А если я пишу sizeof(*str), то, вроде, получаю размер массива указателей, но у меня выводиться всегда 1 (при вводе пустой строки, строки "ABCadekkkll" и других строк в str). Почему так происходит? И возможно ли вообще узнать размер массива указателей?

```
int createOrderedString(char*& newStr, const char* str) {
    const int nSymbol = 256;
    std::cout << sizeof(str) << " " << sizeof(*str) << std::endl;
    int* symbolArray = new int[nSymbol] {0};
    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        symbolArray[str[i]] += 1;
    }
    int lengthNewStr = sizeof(str);
    newStr = new char[lengthNewStr + 1];
    int tempIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < nSymbol; ++i) {
        if (symbolArray[i] > 0) {
            newStr[tempIndex] = i;
            ++tempIndex;
        }
    }
    newStr[lengthNewStr + 1] = '\0';
    delete[] symbolArray;
    return tempIndex;
}
```

Comment: Тут нигде нет массива указателей. Посредством `sizeof` невозможно узнать размер или количество элементов массива по указателю на его элемент. Используйте `array_view` или `string_view`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут нет **массива указателей**. Есть указатель на константную строку символов (указатель на массив). Чтоб найти её длину, нужно использовать `strlen`, если строка сформирована по правилам, заканчиваясь нулём. Иначе передавайте её длину ещё одним параметром.